# ¿Cómo asigno secciones de Google?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Una vez que monté mi página, la busqué en el navegador y me aparece con diferentes secciones como el ejemplo de la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En un inicio, la diseñé por diferentes archivos HTMLs, pero ahora la actualicé y cargué todo a mi `index.html` como el siguiente:

```
<!-- SECCION 1 -->
    <article class="bckgnd">
        <!-- CONTENIDO DE SECCION -->
    </article>

<!-- SECCION 2 -->
    <article class="bckgnd">
        <!-- CONTENIDO DE SECCION -->
    </article>

<!-- SECCION 3 -->
    <article class="bckgnd">
        <!-- CONTENIDO DE SECCION -->
    </article>

<!-- SECCION 4 -->
    <article class="bckgnd">
        <!-- CONTENIDO DE SECCION -->
    </article>

<!-- SECCION 5 -->
    <article class="bckgnd">
        <!-- CONTENIDO DE SECCION -->
    </article>

<!-- SECCION 6 -->
    <article class="bckgnd">
        <!-- CONTENIDO DE SECCION -->
    </article>

<!-- SECCION 7 -->
    <article class="bckgnd">
        <!-- CONTENIDO DE SECCION -->
    </article>
```

Sin embargo, las diferentes secciones que Google creó ahora me redirigen al **Error 404**.
¿Cómo puedo redirigir las diferentes secciones del mismo `index.html` a las que me genera Google por defecto?

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta corta: no puedes.

Respuesta larga: Google lo hará automáticamente si tu sitio está estructurado de manera correcta... y creo que al haber cambiado el sitio y poner todo el contenido en una sola página, los enlaces no se actualizarán (o se borrarán).

Según el sitio de [Ayuda de Google Search](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=es) (resaltado por mí):

> Únicamente mostramos enlaces de sitios en los resultados cuando consideramos que serán útiles para el usuario. **Si la estructura de tu sitio no permite que nuestros algoritmos encuentren enlaces de sitios de calidad o si no consideramos que tu sitio contenga enlaces relevantes para la consulta del usuario, no los mostraremos**.
>
> Actualmente, los enlaces de sitios aparecen de forma automática. Trabajamos continuamente para mejorar nuestros algoritmos de enlaces de sitios, y podríamos incorporar la colaboración del webmaster en un futuro. También existen prácticas recomendadas que puedes seguir para mejorar la calidad de los enlaces de sitios. Por ejemplo, asegúrate de que el texto de anclaje y el texto alternativo de los enlaces internos del sitio sean informativos y compactos, y que no resulten repetitivos.

Antes tu sitio web tenía diferentes páginas enlazadas, esos enlaces se usaron para crear los enlaces de sitio. Ahora todo el contenido está en una sola página, por lo que no va a haber enlaces que mostrar.

Sobre el problema de 404, puedes ir a la consola de Google y pedir que vuelvan a indexar tu página, pero entonces seguramente pierdas los enlaces de sitio en los resultados.